# Permission for all Entries in a Channel

Tags: channel, permissions

Is it possible to assign a group of members some permissions based on channel?

For example, assume that I have channel_1 and channel_2, and group_1. Can I give group_1 edit permission to all entries in channel_1 but not allow them to edit entries in channel_2? How? The documentation is not clear on that.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Found it. It is under Members > Groups > Edit Group